# Can a 220V US circuit have more than one 220V outlet, by code?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

When I move the laundry, I'm considering switching to a gas drier -- but even so it'd be nice to have the 220V drop there for future-proofing.

However, if I'm not using it for the drier, I'd like to have it available in the workshop. Perhaps even if the drier *is* hooked up to it; I have the house to myself and don't need to do laundry and woodworking simultaneously.

So: Rumor has it that code would only allow one outlet per 220V circuit, to prevent any risk of simultaneous use. Is this true? If so I would need to either delay installing the new drier outlet, or spring for another pair of breakers (meaning more doubles to make room or a secondary box), or both. Or perhaps code would let me use the existing drier run to feed a secondary box, and pull the new drier drop off that? (Wouldn't be a bad thing for the workshop to have its own box anyway, perhaps with lockout or EPO...)

I know, I'm overcomplicating things. Just juggling ideas to see which ones fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code doesn't care if you say you're not going to use stuff at the same time, it assumes you will.

I don't think it would be a code violation to have multiple outlets on a 240 volt circuit (though I could be wrong). The number of outlets is not restricted (at least not that I've seen), based on voltage.

However, the conductors have to be sized for the load, and the overcurrent protection sized to protect the conductors.  So in an existing install, you'll be limited by the size of the conductors that are installed.

My advice would be to remove the dryer receptacle, or run a new circuit for the workshop. If you remove the dryer receptacle, you can extend the circuit to the shop from the junction box.  Then you have the option to go back to a dryer hookup.

Comment: Understood and agreed re assuming worst case in code and in conductor size. . And yeah,  my current plan is just the shop... but I wanted to check the rules.

Comment: Why would it matter how many outlets there were?  I can have ten 5-15 duplex outlets on a 20A breaker.  That's 300 Amps if you use the same rationale applied here with dryer outlets!  But it's ok because the breaker protects the wiring.  Similarly it's ok to have five dryer outlets on one 30 amp circuit if you want to.  Just know that it you ever try to use > 30 amps at a time you're going to be stopped by the breaker.

Answer (score 2):

I'd drop in a sub-panel and run circuits from there. Overload would blow the sub-panel breaker.

Unlikely that a shop and dryer would be used simultaneously causing an overload.

Same thinking using a dryer circuit to charge an EV.

Comment: That's roughly what I was thinking. And I'd need a junction box to extend the line anyway; putting in a small panel wouldn't complicate matters much.